# How to Count the number of active user in a website without using database or saving number in file using PHP

Tags: php

How to Count the number of active user in a website without using database or saving number in file using PHP.

ex. you and i are login/using a website how can i know that there are 2 active users in the wbsite?

Does anyone know a function/method for this?

Comment: You're going to need some kind of persistence.

Answer (score 3):

If the case for 'active users' is a login and session, and you have coded your site such that only logged in users get a session, you could get a rough estimate of 'active users' by counting the number of files in the php session directory. For example, assuming your session is set to `/var/lib/php/session` you could run something like this periodically.

> ls -l /var/lib/php/session | wc -l

Comment: `count(glob(session_save_path() . '*')` might be quicker, and would not require firing up a shell. But otherwise, yes, very good/quick method to do this without having to implement some kind of accounting system.

Comment: I think this is about the best you can do without some method of storing a counter. +1

Comment: Hi thanks i think this is the answer on my question.. last one may i ask you another situation, What if i don't have a login module but i want to count who's currently visiting the website.? thanks in advance. you help a lot.

Comment: That's a really interesting approach to the problem. You're kind of counting for garbage collection to have been run recently, but in terms of ease of use this should cut it.